# Kendo grid - show pagination total from json

Tags: javascript, json, pagination, kendo-grid

I am developing a kendo grid.In this on main row I am showing File type and their total count and when expand this row then show all data in pagination.

In my json if my total data is 100 then in json only 10 data is present and when click on next page I get next 10 json data.

Now I want to set the total result for pagination but in my sample what is problem I cant identify.

To show this I used following example - 
http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/y6KdK/

In my example I am not sure that my json is wrong or the aproach I used is wrong.

**EDIT**
My code is -

```
    var jsonData = JSON.parse("{\"Report\":\"type1\",\"FileList\":[{\"owner\":\"machine-174\\\\admin\",\"path\":\"C:\\\\workarea\\\\WinTest1lakhfileinKB\\\\WinTest\\\\nGYh\\\\SMv\\\\U1P8FLx\\\\vMbhdo\\\\TgFSW\\\\42Ioulj0w.txt\"},{\"owner\":\"machine-174admin\",\"path\":\"C:\\\\workarea\\\\bada_data\\\\Employee Database - Copy (7) - Copy.mdb\"}],\"Count\":100,\"total\":10}");
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            editable: false,
            resizable: true,
            filterable: true,
            columns: [{
                field: "Report",
                title: "Report"
            }, {
                field: "Count",
                title: "Count"
            }],
            dataSource: {
                data: jsonData,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            Report: {
                                type: "string"
                            },
                            Count: {
                                type: "number"
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            detailInit: function (e) {

                var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    data: e.data.FileList,

                    aggregate: [{
                        field: "size",
                        aggregate: "sum"
                    }],
                   schema:{
                   total:"total"
                   },

                    page: $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page(),
                    pageSize: 10,
                    resizable: true,
                    filterable: true,
                    scrollable: true

                });
                dataSource.fetch(function () {
                    totalsize = null;
                    var result = null;
                    results = dataSource.aggregates().size;
                    totalsize = getSize(results.sum);
                });

                    childheader = "[{\"field\":\"path\",\"title\":\"Path\",\"width\":\"200px\"},{\"field\":\"owner\",\"title\":\"Owner\",\"width\":\"200px\"}]";
                var childhead = JSON.parse(childheader);
                var dataSource = $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: e.data.FileList,
                       total:e.data.total,
                        editable: false,
                        pageSize: 10,
                        scrollable: true,
                        resizable: true,
                        filterable: true,
                        aggregate: [{
                            field: "size",
                            aggregate: "sum"
                        }],
                        schema: {
                          total:"total",
                            parse: function (data) {
                                $.each(data, function (idx, elem) {
                                    elem.size = getSize(elem.size);
                                });
                                return data;
                            },
                            model: {
                                fields: {

                                    path: {
                                        type: "string"
                                    },

                                    owner: {
                                        type: "string"
                                    }


                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    columns: childhead,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    filterable: true,
                    scrollable: true,
                    serverPaging: false,

                    pageable: {
                            pageSize: 2,
                            refresh: true,
                            change:function(e){
                                   console.log("page change event");
                            }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        function getSize(val) {
        var bytes = val;
        var size = null;
        var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB'];
        if (bytes > 0) {
            var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
            size = Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
            return size;
        }
    }
```

My example is here - 
https://jsfiddle.net/pporwal26/2ub1rvc2/8/

In this example I want to show per page 2 data and total 10 pages even if I have 2 data in json and get next page data by page change function.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set your page size and pageable attribute in one:

```
    pageable: {
        input: true,
        numeric: false,
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        pageSize: 10
    },
```

Just bring in your data through your datasource and it will set the grid to each page in increments of 10.

Comment: how can i use this solution for angular kendo grid?